# In nw.js(node-webkit), how node-main : node.js access any windows?

Tags: node.js, node-webkit, nw.js

If window A in `package.json` open a new window B, how can node-main access it?
heres is my code:

package.json

```
 {
      "main": "index.html",
      "name": "Hello NW.js",
      "node-main": "nodemain.js",
      "window": {
        "toolbar": true 
      }
 }
```

index.html

```
  <body>
    <script src="test.js">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

test.js

```
var gui = require('nw.gui'); 
var win = gui.Window.get();
var testval = "window1"
var test = function()
{
    alert(testval);
};
gui.Window.open ('index2.html', {});
```

index2.html

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script src="test2.js">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

test2.js

```
var gui = require('nw.gui'); 
var win = gui.Window.get();

var testval = "window2";
var test = function()
{
    alert(testval);
};
```

And here is nodemain.js

```
setTimeout(function() {
  var gui = window.require('nw.gui');
  gui.Window.get().test();
}, 1000);
```

When I start, there have a alert window says: window1. How can let is call funcation in test2.js which is included in index2.html, make the alert window say:window2?

Answer (score 0):

Better way to access window objects from `nodemain.js` is that you should save the reference of window objects in `nodemain.js` as window loads.This is because node-main script starts first and windows open afterwards.

So in your `test.js` you can call node process and save the window reference in node context using process.mainModule.[exports](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/node-main)

**In your nodemain.js**

```
var windowMap = {};  //map that will store window references

// exporting this function to access it from process.mainmodule.exports
exports.saveWindow = function(name, winObj){
    windowMap[name] = winObj;
}; 

setTimeout(function() {
    windowMap['win1'].test();
    windowMap['win2'].test();
}, 1000);
```

In your `test.js` you are going to save the [Window](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/window) reference in node context by calling `saveWindow` method from node. Also you are going to save the reference of your test functions in Window objects.

**In test.js**

```
var gui = require('nw.gui');
var win = gui.Window.get();

var testval = "window1";
win.test = function()
{
    alert(testval);
};

var win2 = gui.Window.open ('index2.html', {});

// calling saveWindow from node context
process.mainModule.exports.saveWindow('win1', win);
process.mainModule.exports.saveWindow('win2', win2);
```

**In test2.js**

```
var gui = require('nw.gui');
var win = gui.Window.get();

var testval = "window2";
win.test = function()
{
    alert(testval);
};
```

When nodemain.js `setTimeout` will call, it will have Window object and will successfully call the test methods that are bind to Window objects.